# flask is working inside container but not when I port forward it

Tags: python, docker, flask

What I'm trying: I'm trying to run a simple flask app using docker. Using [this](http://containertutorials.com/docker-compose/flask-simple-app.html) site as a reference.

My dockerfile:

```
FROM ubuntu:latest
RUN apt-get update -y
RUN apt-get install -y python-pip python-dev build-essential
COPY ./app /app
WORKDIR /app
RUN pip install -r "requirements.txt"
ENTRYPOINT ["python"]
CMD ["app.py"]
```

Python file:

```
from flask import Flask
app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/')
def hello():
    return 'Hello World!'

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(port=5000, debug=True)
```

requirements.txt:

```
Flask==1.0.2
```

What I'm doing:

- building image using `docker build -t simple-flask2 .`
- then, starting the container using `docker run -p 5000:5000 simple-flask2`
- the when I go to `localhost:5000` nothing appears.
- So, I opened the container's terminal using `docker exec -it 3be bash` & then did `curl localhost:5000`. To my surprise it **was working inside the container**.

Can anyone please point out what am I missing? I'm pretty new to this. TIA :)

Answer (score 20, accepted):

I guess it is running only on the localhost (default value `host='127.0.0.1'`) in the container. Try to use all interfaces (`host='0.0.0.0'`):

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(port=5000, debug=True, host='0.0.0.0')
```

Comment: Thank you it worked :). Can you please explain what was the issue with not providing `'host'` in `app.run` ?

Comment: all my love for you @Jan

Answer (score 6):

Try listening on every interface with:

```
app.run(host='0.0.0.0', port=5000, debug=True)
```

Comment: Thank you it worked :). Can you please explain what was the issue with not providing `'host'` in `app.run` ?

Comment: I believe that it listens on 127.0.0.1(localhost) by default, as Jan said. Listening on 0.0.0.0 will allow you to access it via your container's network.