# docker-compose up not forwarding port

Tags: python, docker, docker-compose

I have the following files.  When I run docker-compose up -d and exec into the docker container, I am able to run http://127.0.0.1:5000 and get back results.  From the host I get back:

```
user@ubuntu:~/projects/grip/glm-plotter$ curl -v http://localhost:5000
* Rebuilt URL to: http://localhost:5000/
*   Trying ::1...
* TCP_NODELAY set
* Connected to localhost (::1) port 5000 (#0)
> GET / HTTP/1.1
> Host: localhost:5000
> User-Agent: curl/7.58.0
> Accept: */*
> 
* Empty reply from server
* Connection #0 to host localhost left intact
curl: (52) Empty reply from server
```

If I run the docker-compose command without a -d, it starts up but from a separate terminal I also get back empty results.

docker ps (When running without -d)

```
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE               COMMAND                  CREATED             STATUS              PORTS                    NAMES
237b0a7f8710        glm-plotter_web     "python3 glm-plotter…"   16 minutes ago      Up 24 seconds       0.0.0.0:5000->5000/tcp   glm-plotter_web_1
```

I'm not sure if the process should be listed under "docker-proxy":

```
user@ubuntu:~$ sudo netstat -tulpn | grep 5000 
tcp6       0      0 :::5000                 :::*                    `LISTEN      13785/docker-proxy`
```

Dockerfile

```
FROM library/python:3.6-stretch
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y python3
RUN apt-get install -y python3-pip
RUN apt-get install -y build-essential

COPY requirements.txt /
RUN pip3 install --trusted-host pypi.org -r /requirements.txt
RUN pip3 install --upgrade numpy
ADD ./glm-plotter /code
WORKDIR /code
RUN ls .
CMD ["python3", "glm-plotter.py"]
```

docker-compose.yml

```
version: "3"
services:
  web:
    volumes:
      - ~/.aws:/root/.aws
    build: .
    ports:
      - "5000:5000"
```

Comment: Is it possible that glm-plotter.py is bound only to 127.0.0.1? When you run a web server inside a container it should listen to every IP since localhost is the container

Comment: @Ignacio Millán, yeah, that was the problem!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your `glm-plotter.py` is listening only on the `localhost` in the container. Your app must be listening on all interfaces in the container - TCP host `0.0.0.0`, not just `locahost/127.0.0.1` - you need to fix your python code.

It is a common issue - flask example: [flask is working inside container but not when I port forward it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52604864/flask-is-working-inside-container-but-not-when-i-port-forward-it/52604953#52604953)