# "Problem loading Page" Flask App using docker

Tags: python, flask

I am trying to run a flask app using a docker.
Operating system Windows 11, WSL image Ubuntu-20.04.
A simple reproducible example:
https://github.com/Konrad-H/stackoverflow-question

If I run (inside a venv)

```
$ python app/main.py
```

the following message appears in the console:

```
Running on http://127.0.0.1:5000/ (Press CTRL+C to quit)
```

And I can successfully connect to the app.

On the other hand, if I try to run the repo using:

```
$ docker build -t s-o-question:latest .
$ docker run -p 5000:5000 s-o-question
```

I get the exact same message on the console, but the webpage takes a long time loading and after a while a [connection timeout](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qkFlD.png) appears.

The error appears both inside WSL2 and inside Windows.

Source Code:

`main.py`

```
import logging

from flask import Flask, render_template, request

app = Flask(__name__)


@app.route("/")
def index():
    print("Hello World I am Sea")
    return "Hello big world"


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.logger = logging.getLogger("audio-gui")
    app.run( host='0.0.0.0',port=5000, debug=True)
```

`Dockerfile`

```
FROM python:3.8

# Working Directory
WORKDIR /app

# Copy source code to working directory
COPY . ./app /app/

# Install packages from requirements.txt
# hadolint ignore=DL3013
RUN pip install --no-cache-dir --upgrade pip &&\
    pip install --no-cache-dir --trusted-host pypi.python.org -r requirements.txt

EXPOSE 5000

ENTRYPOINT [ "python" ]

CMD [ "app/main.py" ]
```

Comment: This may go away if you serve your app to 0.0.0.0 instead of to 127.0.0.1. See this for more details: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52604864/flask-is-working-inside-container-but-not-when-i-port-forward-it

Comment: @Salmonstrikes The app is set to 0.0.0.0. I already tried the solution proposed on that question. Added the sourcecode directly to the question.

Comment: Your container works fine on my Debian VM. I'd guess something to do with your Windows 10/11 network configuration...

Comment: Thank you @Salmonstrikes. I supoosed it was something of the sort.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue. The URL `http/localhost:5000/` worked for me (5000 is my exposed port number). you can try and see if it works. Alternatively, you can also try `http://<host-ip>:5000/`. Note that the `host-ip` should be IP address of your local machine not the IP address of the docker container.

you can also check this [answer](https://forums.docker.com/t/failed-to-connect-to-172-17-0-2-port-8080-connection-refused/116894#:%7E:text=Or%20you%20can%20connect%20to%20your%20host%E2%80%99s%20port%208080%20(i.e.%20http%3A//%3Chost%2Dip%3E%3A8080/%20or%20maybe%20http%3A//localhost%3A8080/))

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that you cannot use same port number for ex if your app runs on port 5000 it must be bind to another port like 8080 in docker .
try this  `docker run -p 8080:5000 s-o-question`
I had the same issue on my win 11 device , i worked around this using the above solution.